# Quisiera saber como puedo solucionar este error en Angular cuando quiero compilar y correr el proyecto con ng-serve

Tags: angular

Luego de instalar el paquete node_modules para poder correr el proyecto mediante el comando ng-serve me tira el siguiente error:

**ERROR in Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/util/decorators from ..................\Users\juanf\Desktop\asdf\asdf\asdf\dashboard\node_modules@angular\core\core.d.ts**

---

Localmente tengo instalada la version de Angular 12 pero el proyecto esta hecho en Angular 7, por esto me tira la siguiente advertencia, podria ser parte del problema?

Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.10) is greater than your local version (7.3.10). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

[image: captura]

Comment: Por un lado, hay una ruta muy extensa, crea una carpeta en la raíz del disco, por ejemplo: `C:\Dev\Projecto`

Comment: Creo sinceramente que es un problema relacionado a la versión de angular.  Angular 7 usa typescript 3.x.x, mientras angular 12 usa 4.x.x. Por el versionado semántico asumo que son incompatibles. Te recomiendo actualizar tu proyecto con [angular.io/update](https://angular.io/update) Solo que has una rama nueva en git para hacer la actualización. Si no quieres actualizar, haz un downgrade de tu cli a la v7 de angular.

Answer (score 0):

> la advertencia que te da sobre la version puede ser una causa
> podes actualizar  intentando que el UPDATE corrija el error
> [vinculo con detalles de como actualizar](https://update.angular.io/)
> podrias tambien copiar el codigo de tu package.json y mas
> datos para ver mejor el problema

Fuente update.angular.io  no soporta migrar saltando versiones

```
Antes del Update verificar si usas  HttpClientModule y HttpClient service.

Durante el Update
```

> 1.`npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8`
>
> 2.`(deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep`
>
> 3.verificar estar usando versión >v14.15.0de Node
> 4.  using dynamic .imports...>loadChildren is deprecated -->verificar que se usa nueva
> sintaxis   `loadChildren: () => import(:..)`
>
> 5.`npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`
>
> 6. `npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9`
>
> 7.`ng add @angular/localize`
>
> 8. `npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10`
> 9. ng update
>
> 10.`npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11`
>
> 11. ng update
> 12. `npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`
>
> 13.ng update